# Transforming nested JSON to simple dictionary JSON structure

Tags: python, json

I'm calling an API which returns me data in such a format:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "columns": [
        {
          "fieldNameOrPath": "Name",
          "value": "Burlington Textiles Weaving Plant Generator"
        },
        {
          "fieldNameOrPath": "AccountName",
          "value": "Burlington Textiles Corp of America"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "columns": [
        {
          "fieldNameOrPath": "Name",
          "value": "Dickenson Mobile Generators"
        },
        {
          "fieldNameOrPath": "AccountName",
          "value": "Dickenson plc"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

in order to properly use this data for my following workflow I need a structure such as:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "Name": "Burlington Textiles Weaving Plant Generator",
      "AccountName": "Burlington Textiles Corp of America"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Dickenson Mobile Generators",
      "AccountName": "Dickenson plc"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the `fieldNameOrPath` value needs to become the key and the `value` value needs to become the value.

Can this transformation be done with a python function?

Those conditions apply:

- I don't know how many objects will be inside each `columns` list element
- The key and the value names could be different (so I need to pass `fieldNameOrPath` as the key for the key and `value` as the key for the value to the function in order to specify them)

Comment: yes, it could be done in python. iterate over elements in `records` and for each element - iterate over `columns` creating key:value pair as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll suppose the data from the API is stored in a variable `data`. To get the data transformed into the format you propose, we can iterate through all the records, and for each record create a dictionary by iterating through its columns, using the `fieldNameOrPath` values as the keys, and the `value` values as the dictionary values.

```py
trans_data = {"records": []}

for record in data["records"]:
    trans_record = {}
    for column in record["columns"]:
        trans_record[column["fieldNameOrPath"]] = column["value"]

    trans_data["records"].append(trans_record)
```